# How do I clip drawing to bounds in Flash?

Tags: flash

I'm using the Graphics object in Flash but I can't seem to clip drawing to bounds. Whenever I draw the bounds get upgraded dynamically. What I want is to set a given fixed bound and clip all drawing outside of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could mask the MovieClip you're drawing to.

Answer (score 0):

mask your clip:

```
var someMask:Sprite = new Sprite();
someMask.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0);
someMask.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
someMask.graphics.endFill();
this.addChild(someMask);

someClipYouWantToMask.mask = someMask;
```

or set its scrollRect prop

```
someClipYouWantToMask.scrollRect(new rectangle(0,0,100,100));
```